# How to get total number of x displayed in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider:

```
x <- rnorm(100)
qplot(x)
```

How to I get the total number `(N = 100)` of `x` displayed on the top right corner in my ggplot?

See actual output:

[image]

See this example `(N = 37)`:

[image]

Comment: I hate that bottom graph

Comment: How comes? What would you make different, Dason?

Comment: Use `geom_text` for your annotation. I agree with Dason... I'd make it less terrible, since there's basically nothing good about it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Alex. I am just curious: what is terrible about the example graph?

Comment: FWIW ggplot2 2.0 has `geom_label` which has options for the background rectangle as well as the text element.

Comment: @TilHund Can you name one good thing about it? It takes up more room than a corresponding table of the raw data and adds nothing really.  It's an overall negative since it's actually even harder to read this than a raw table would be. There are equal physical spacing along the x-axis but the values are just whatever the data calls for. It's just not good... at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of ways. `geom_text` is the most general tool. For a one-off label, maybe `annotate`:

```
qplot(x) + 
   annotate("text",x = Inf,y = Inf,label = "N = 100",hjust = 1.5,vjust = 1.5)
```

Comment: In the end this has helped me! Thank you very much! I thank you all guys. I think that all answers are great!

Answer (score 4):

You can also set the location of the label programmatically, based on the data values. `ggplot2` defaults to 30 bins, so the code below uses 30 bins to set the y-value for the label location:

```
set.seed(101)
x <- rnorm(100)

qplot(x) + 
  annotate("text", label=paste0("N = ", length(x)), x=max(x), y=max(table(cut(x, 30))))
```

or

```
qplot(x) + 
  geom_text(aes(label=paste0("N = ", length(x)), x=max(x), y=max(table(cut(x, 30)))))
```

**UPDATE:** To address your comment, let's plot with a discrete x vector. Now if we still want the y position of the text to be at the maximum, we once again find the category with the maximum number of counts. The data are already discrete, so we just need `y=max(table(x))`. For the x position, if we want the label at the maximum x value, we need the number of unique x categories, since ggplot implicitly numbers these from 1 to the N (where N is the number of categories). The `unique` function returns a vector containing each unique category. We just need the length of this vector to get the maximum x value in the graph: `x=length(unique(x))`.

```
set.seed(101)
x <- cut(rnorm(100), 5)

qplot(x) + 
  geom_text(aes(label=paste0("N = ", length(x)), x=length(unique(x)), y=max(table(x))))
```

Comment: Good addition with the `max()`.

Comment: I like your answer eipi10. However, by trying to implement your solution on my real code, I figured out that I have a discrete x scale of age groups (like 0-4, 5-10 etc.). Because of that `y=max(table(cut(x, 30)))` does not place the output on the top right corner but rather somewhere in between two geom_bars. An i.e. `y=10` gives me an error message that `y has to be >0`. How can I implement your solution on a graph with grouped x values?

Comment: @TilHund, "_I figured out that I have a discrete x scale of …_" –why it's a good idea to make your working example match your _real_ situation as closely as you can.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers show how you can add the text to your plot. But `annotate()` can also be used to add other geoms. If you want to put your annotation inside a rectangle, for instance, you can do the following:

```
x0 <- max(x)
y0 <- max(table(cut(x, 30)))

qplot(x) + 
   annotate("rect", xmin = x0*.8, xmax = x0*1.2, ymin = y0*.95, ymax = y0*1.05,
            fill = "white", colour = "black") +
   annotate("text", label = paste0("N = ", length(x)), x = x0, y = y0)
```

which gives

[image]

Up to the line that starts with `annotate("rect",` everything is taken from the other answers to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Like this? (code below)

[image]

```
# install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies = TRUE)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(421)
x <- rnorm(100)
qplot(x) + annotate("text", x = 2, y = 15, label = paste("N =", length(x)))
```